# Existing object not found

Tags: r

I call a matrix in my code and `R` tells me that the object was not found, although it clearly exists.

Of course I checked for spelling errors and the typical issues. However, when I run parts of the line, where the error occurs, it finds the object perfectly and prints it as requested. Requesting the object itself does not produce the error either, only running that line of code. 
`print(object)` also works before and after that line.

The line with the issue is:

```
a[h,k]<<-switch(as.character(a[h,k]-1),"0"=-1,a[h,k]-1)
```

`a` is the problematic matrix. It is used within a function, but even when I run the line independent of the function, it doesn't work either. 
`a[h,k]` and `switch(as.character(a[h,k]-1),"0"=-1,a[h,k]-1)` properly work by themselves.

Comment: It is hard to say without a larger context and the exact error message. Why do you use `<<-` (the superassignment operator)? You should avoid using that except in very special situations. Are you sure that `a` is defined in the parent environment?

Comment: Why do you use `switch` when `if ... else ...` would do?

Comment: Isn't the distinction completely unecessary? If it is 0 you set it to -1, else you subtract 1. So 0 is not a special case.